# is there anything similar to Java's string 'charAt()' Method in C?

Tags: java, c

I'm trying to convert a piece of code from Java to C and I got stuck here, trying to get a character at each position.

```
char ch;

line += ' ';
    while (pos < line.length()) 
    {
      ch = line.charAt(pos);  
...
```

is there anything similar in C to convert the line `ch = line.charAt(pos)` from java to C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in C, the easiest way to get a char from an array of character (I.E. a string)

given the variables in your posted code,

```
char ch;

line += ' ';
while (pos < line.length()) 
{
    ch = line.charAt(pos);  
...
```

1. assuming that the string is terminated with a NUL byte ('\0')
2. assuming there is room in the `line[]` array for another character

would become:

```
#include <string.h>
strcat( line, " ");
size_t maxPos = strlen( line );
for( pos = 0; pos < maxPos; pos++ )
{
    ch = line[pos];
....
```

Comment: I used `strcat(line, ' ')` to convert that line, would there be a difference?

Comment: ?? you used `strcat()` to convert which line?  please clarify

Comment: in your code it says `strcat(line, "")` ,I did `strcat(line, '')` what is the difference?

Comment: the `""` is not correct in your comment there is a space between the two double quote marks.  This results in the array line[]` containing one more character (a space) at the end.   the `strcat()` will assure the resulting string still contains a NUL ('\0') byte at the end to terminate the string

Comment: *what is the difference?*  a double quite is a string terminated with a NUL char, a single quote is a single character.  the function: `strcat()` requires that both parameters are pointers NUL terminated char arrays (I.E. pointers to strings)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the values as though the String was an array.

```
char str[] = "Hello World";
printf("%c", str[0]);
```

Comment: Fixed to match C definiton, nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a character at specific position in this way

```
char str[] = "Anything";
printf("%c", str[0]);
```

but when you have a pointer array:

```
char* an_array_of_strings[]={"balloon", "whatever", "isnext"};
cout << an_array_of_strings[1][2] << endl;
```

If you need to change the strings use

```
char an_array_of_strings[][20]={"balloon", "whatever", "isnext"};
cout << an_array_of_strings[1][2] << endl;
```

source: [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/25406-anything-similar-to-charat-in-c/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!